# How to Pass the list of records to a method and skip all the passed records

Tags: c#, .net, loops

This is my `Attendance` class

```
public class EmployeeAttendance
{
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeClockTimeId { get; set; }
}
```

Logic

```
        List<EmployeeAttendance> attendancesPerDay = new List<EmployeeAttendance>();
        List<EmployeeAttendance> employeeAttendances = new List<EmployeeAttendance>();
        foreach (var attendance in employeeAttendances)
        {
            if (attendancesPerDay.Contains(attendance))
            {
                continue;
            }
            attendancesPerDay = employeeAttendances.Where(x => x.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && x.EmployeeClockTimeId == 12.ToString()).ToList();
            Validation(attendancesPerDay);
        }
```

I will have of `employeeAttendances`. this contains all the employee attendance as date wise. This will be a big list. I need to send the set of records to the validation method as per day and empid. I'm achieving it through the above code. but its taking much time. Is there a better way to do it like skip all the `AttendancesPerDay` records not like going one by one in a loop.

Note: in one day there will be multiple entries like every time emp went out and came in. let say 20 records. I want all the 20 records to send it to validation. and the next iteration has to be 21 records. but now I'm just continuing up to that point

Comment: Out of interest, why do you use `12.ToString()` instead of `"12"`?

Comment: @John I was just checking.it sort of came like that no reasons

Comment: `EmployeeAttandance` in foreach is `List<EmployeeAttandance>` ? Why you set `AttandancePerDay ` in every foreach iteration if you don't use `Attandance` varaible? Does this code compile at all?

Comment: @Okamyra  EmployeeAttandance in foreach is List<EmployeeAttandance> ? yes it is ,foreach iteration if you don't use Attandance varaible? Attandance is used  `if (AttandancePerDay.Contains(Attandance))` here Does this code compile at all? Yes

Comment: @Okamyra U mean `Validation(Attendance)` If yes I can't do it as the Validation method required all the records of a single emp per day

Comment: @Avinash So you have `employeeAttendances` - big list of all emp with Attendance from all days. And you have `attendancesPerDay` - list of Attendance for only today. What do you want? To validate only today OR validate all except today? If first - you dont need `foreach` at all - just call `Validation(employeeAttendances.Where(x => x.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && x.EmployeeClockTimeId == 12.ToString()).ToList())`

Comment: @Okamyra in one day there will be multiple entries like every time emp went out and came in let say 20 records I want all the 20 records to send it to validation and next iteration has to be 21 record. but now I'm just continuing up to that point

Comment: @Avinash Try this `foreach (var attendance in employeeAttendances.GroupBy(x => x.Employee))
                Validation(attendance.Where(x => x.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && x.EmployeeClockTimeId == 12.ToString()).ToList());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought too much maybe. that's why I missed this simple thing. I end up using like this

```
        for (int i = 0; i < EmployeeAttandance.Count; i++)
        {
            var attendancesPerDay = EmployeeAttandance.Where(x => x.Date.Date == EmployeeAttandance[i].Date.Date && x.EmployeeClockTimeID == EmployeeAttandance[i].EmployeeClockTimeID).ToList();
            Validation(attendancesPerDay);
            i = EmployeeAttandance.IndexOf(attendancesPerDay[attendancesPerDay.Count - 1]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can Use `IEnumerable<TSource>.Except` method in linq and impelement `IEqualityComparer<EmployeeAttendance>` for your `EmployeeAttendance` class.

```
public class EmployeeAttendanceEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<EmployeeAttendance>
    {
        public bool Equals(EmployeeAttendance x, EmployeeAttendance y)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null)
                return false;

            // check your equality same as this
            return x.Employee == y.Employee;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(EmployeeAttendance obj)
        {
            // or something else
            return 12;
        }
    }
```

and change your logic to this

```
var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

var attendancesPerDay = new List<EmployeeAttendance>
{
    new EmployeeAttendance { Date = currentTime, Employee = "1", EmployeeClockTimeId = "11" },
    new EmployeeAttendance { Date = currentTime, Employee = "2", EmployeeClockTimeId = "12" },
    new EmployeeAttendance { Date = currentTime, Employee = "3", EmployeeClockTimeId = "13" },
    new EmployeeAttendance { Date = currentTime, Employee = "4", EmployeeClockTimeId = "14" },
    new EmployeeAttendance { Date = currentTime, Employee = "5", EmployeeClockTimeId = "15" },
};

var employeeAttendances = new List<EmployeeAttendance>
{
    new EmployeeAttendance { Date = currentTime, Employee = "1", EmployeeClockTimeId = "11" },
    new EmployeeAttendance { Date = currentTime, Employee = "2", EmployeeClockTimeId = "12" },
    new EmployeeAttendance { Date = currentTime, Employee = "3", EmployeeClockTimeId = "13" },
};

var result = attendancesPerDay
    .Except(employeeAttendances, new EmployeeAttendanceEqualityComparer())
    .Where(x => x.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && x.EmployeeClockTimeId == "12").ToList();

foreach (EmployeeAttendance employeeAttendance in result)
{
    Validation(employeeAttendance);
}
```

Comment: is there is any problem with my logic which is mentioned in answer?

Comment: In your ans, how can I add this condition `x.Date.Date == EmployeeAttandance[i].Date.Date && x.EmployeeClockTimeID == EmployeeAttandance[i].EmployeeClockTimeID`

Comment: I include this condition after the `Except` method.